# Как правильно организовать очерёдность запросов к api vk?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Столкнулся с проблемой. "В контакте" присылает моему приложению через колбэк сообщение от юзера. Чтобы отправить юзеру ответ, приложение делает 3 запроса к апи. 
Когда сообщений было мало, всё работало хорошо. Но теперь, в часы пик, лимит (3 запроса в сек) превышается и вк блокирует запросы.
Вопрос: как правильно организовать очередь - чтобы несмотря на большое количество сообщений на входе, приложение стабильно обращалось к апи 3 раза в секунду.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute) для оптимизации

Comment: Оно картинку загружает. 1) запрашивает сервер; 2) загружает; 3) сохраняет; 4) отправляет. Из-за загрузки не получится в этот метод упаковать.

Comment: Типа стека что-то нужно. Только как его организовать? В бд записывать, а потом обрабатывать. Или массив.

Comment: Мда… тогда я бы реализовывал нечто с помощью дополнительного потока, который только шлёт запросы к ВК и переодически засыпает, если нужно. Для синхронизации воспользовался бы [MessageQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.messaging.messagequeue(v=vs.110).aspx). Когда основному потоку надо отправить ВКшное сообщение, он кладёт его в очередь, а основной поток просыпается либо по таймеру, либо по появлению нового сообщения для отправки. Но возможно, есть способ и проще